# Convert a long string of coordinates into a list

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, int, coordinates

I have a long string of coordinates divided by commas.

```
['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']
```

What is the easiest way to convert this string into a list of coordinates like the one below?

```
[(22.98795, 74.5936), (55.26964, 124.43686), (39.34479, 124.53541)]
```

I hope there is an easier solution than this

```py
coords = "['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']"
x = coords.split("', '")
x[0] = x[0][2:]
x[-1] = x[-1][:-2]
```

Comment: Whats wrong with that solution?

Comment: How is that desired result "a list of int"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> coords = "['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']"
>>> l = literal_eval(coords)
>>> l
['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']
>>> [tuple(map(float, i.split(','))) for i in l]
[(22.98795, 74.5936), (55.26964, 124.43686), (39.34479, 124.53541)]
```

As a one-liner:

```
coords = [tuple(map(float, i.split(','))) for i in literal_eval(coords)]
```

Or, since `22.98795, 74.5936` happens to be a valid literal for a tuple, use `literal_eval` for it again:

```
coords = list(map(literal_eval, literal_eval(coords)))
```

Comment: Or `[literal_eval(s) for s in l]`.

Answer (score 0):

You might improve original method by using `.strip` method of `str` that is:

```
coords = "['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']"
x = coords.strip("[']").split("', '")
print(x)
```

Output:

```
['22.98795, 74.5936', '55.26964, 124.43686', '39.34479, 124.53541']
```

strip removes leading and trailing character it get in argument. Keep in mind `x` is `list` of `str`, which need further processing if you need `tuple`s of `float`s.