# Converting list of string coordinate to list of tuple coordinates

Tags: python

I currently have a list of string coordinates, this however, when trying to use it for external modules as a coordinate list. I am basically trying to use this list of points in order to plot a map. This is not possible when the list is formatted like this:

`list = ['(23,45)','(25,23)']`

In order to use the elements in the list as coordinates I need the list to be formatted like this:

`list = [(23,45),(25,23)]`

Currently I have tried to follow this post:
[Convert a long string of coordinates into a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63248021/convert-a-long-string-of-coordinates-into-a-list)

However, it has come to no use.

I have not seen a post on here explaining the problem I am trying to solve which leads me to post, thank you in advance!

Comment: It's basically the same as that question, you just have a *list of* string representations, so you need to iterate over it: `list = [literal_eval(i) for i in list]`. Or `list = list(map(literal_eval, list))`

Comment: does this help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21735859/convert-a-string-which-is-a-list-into-a-proper-list-python

Answer (score 0):

You could use [ast](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to decode the tuple from each such string.

```
from ast import literal_eval as make_tuple
print(make_tuple('(1,2,3)'))
// Output: (1, 2, 3)
```